# Opencart vqmod 2.3.0.2 $config error

Tags: config, vqmod, opencart2.3

i have just installed opencart 2.3.0.2 and vqmod but i am facing a problem now. In previous version of opencart when i was using the below code in vqmod xml file

```
global $config;
$variableA =  $config->get('field_value');
```

then in $variableA i got the value which i saved in the db from admin section but now in 2.3.0.2 when i use this code it shows fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null
```

please tell me how can i get the value in vqmod xml file so i can use this variable further

Thanks

Comment: Which version of **vQmod** for **Opencart** are you using?

Comment: latest version but global $config in opncart 2.3.0.2 is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable in a file controller first:

`$data['variableA'] = $this->config->get('variableA');`

then (for example) echo the variable in a view file:

`<?php echo $variableA; ?>`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion now i have also call controller code in vqmode xml fine and as you provide the  code its working